# 'getline' was not declared in this scope, what does it mean?

Tags: qnx

When compile, I have 'getline' was not declared in this scope

compiling next code:

```
string PostCmd::getFailedFromFile()
{
    string failedList;
    ifstream file(FILE, ifstream::in);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        getline(file, failedList);
        file.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file";
    }
    return failedList;
}
```

Comment: Try include <istream>

Comment: Yeap, it was helping, Thanks

Comment: I have added it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to include `<istream>`.

More info can be seen here: http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0_sp1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.dinkum_en_ecpp%2Fistream.html